# how to remove space in post url

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I am using the below line to retrieve the permalink for a post type archive.

```
<?php get_post_type_archive_link( $post_type ); ?>
```

When I am using this code it shows the url like this:

```
http://mywebsite.com/about      /
```

I need to remove space between about and '/'. So where i want to change this url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick fix would be to replace spaces with 'nothing' like in the following example.

```
$string = str_replace(' ', '', $string);
```

But I think a core WP method returning a string with spaces is a bit weird. I would check why it returns URL's with spaces, because that is not really normal behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Use following code to remove space in url

```
<?php 
    $url = $get_post_type_archive_link( $post_type ); 
    echo str_replace(' ', '', $url);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You can solve it using two ways 
1. str_replace
2. regex pattern 

1. using str_replace
<?php
$url = "http://www.techiecode.com/ magic- methods-in-php.html ";
echo str_replace(" ", "", $url);
// Output: http://www.techiecode.com/magic-methods-in-php.html
?>

2. using regex pattern
<?php
$string = 'http://www.techiecode.com/ 222magic- methods-in-php.html ';
$pattern = '/( )*/';
$replacement = '';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
// Output: http://www.techiecode.com/222magic-methods-in-php.html

?>
```